# How to test for Normality using my dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, statistics, anova

[This image includes my data I'm using for an ANOVA test.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gk0ue.png)

Using this data, how can I test certain parts or comparisons for normality? For Python3

Answer (score 0):

you could use a qq-plot

```
from statsmodels.graphics.gofplots import qqplot
from matplotlib import pyplot 

column = "column of your dataset"
# q-q plot
qqplot(column, line='s')
pyplot.show()
```

basically the upper end and also the lower end of the Q-Q plot shouldn't deviate from the straight line

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'shape'

Comment: of course, you have to change  column = "column of your dataset";
as a first example you could try to test the normality of age by writing column = subset["Age"]